# How to make environment variable to read the filepath specified in an executable?

Tags: rust, environment-variables, command-line-interface, exe

So my source code look like this:

```rust
use std::env;
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    let file = &args[1];

    let fileContent = fs::read_to_string("./".to_owned() + file).expect("file cannot be found");
    println!("File content: {}\n", fileContent);

    let a = std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut String::new()).unwrap();
}
```

the code is written in Rust programming language to make a command line interface program.

Since, in Rust the executable is inside the `/target/debug/` directory, I can set the full path of the executable in the environment variable, with a name called `CLI_RUST`, so that I can call the executable from anywhere of my local file hierarchy.

The problem is, when I tried to invoke the .exe file anywhere except the exact directory of the binary, the environment is able to execute that binary but could not find the file specified in the binary (.exe) file.

I already tried the full path of .txt file to be read from the binary but still it throws exception. Only success is when I enter the exact directory of the binary, then it will work as intended.

So how to overcome this?

Comment: You're concatenating `./` to the path (current directory), so of course you cannot pass an absolute path. Get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, my full path definition is incorrect, I should add the `\\` at the end of my absolute file path string, because later I want to append it to a file name.

for example:

`c:\\global\\first\\second\\`.to_owned()+file;

instead of just:

`c:\\global\\first\\second`.to_owned()+file;

Because this is what I initially written by me thought it would be the full path.